# Build vs Construct

Tags: word-meaning, word-difference, word-in-context

I have noticed an interesting thing going on with these two words. Somehow they add-up to each other instead of being interchangeable while being so close in meaning.

- We can build a house but the place where we do it is called a construction site.
- We can construct a house but the result will be a building and not a construction.
- We can build a house and then reconstruct it but we can't construct a house and then rebuild it.

In some cases a construction is a building and vice versa.

Am I right in my explorations?

Comment: I suspect that's the same thing but the origins are different, that is, Anglo - Saxons for the word build and Latin for the word construct. But, certainly, in time, each one acquired specific connotations.

Answer (score 4):

For me, a British person, ***build*** is associated with everyday items such as houses, roads, bridges, office buildings etc.

The word ***construct***, to me suggests a requirement for an element of ingenuity. *They are going to construct an underground reservoir/ a space station/ a hydro-electric dam that utilises its own electricity etc.*

**If it is bulk standard, it is built, if it is something new and ingenious it is constructed.** That is my basic sense of the two words. Though it is a general comment which I accept is not true 100% of the time.

I do not believe we use ***construct*** nearly as often as do Americans. Hardly anyone would say, for example, *they are going to construct a house on the site*. For such everyday things it would always be ***build, building site*** etc.

As regards ***building*** and ***construction***, if it is occupied by people (e.g. house, office block, department store, factory) it will be a *building*, if it is a device that is either ornamental (e.g. The Angel of the North) or useful (e.g. a gantry crane for unloading vehicles) it is a *construction*.

Comment: For me, an American person, I would say the same thing exactly. But I do not believe the verb construct is used more by Americans. It is used more in **certain** contexts: to construct an argument or to construct an alibi. Also, your examples with reservoir etc. And am I not right in thinking that would be same for you? Then, there's always the fact that some people only like to deal in cónstructs. :)

Comment: @Lambie Umm. I'm sure you must be right. But I seem to hear Americans in my mind talking about a *construction site*. Indeed that is how the OP starts out.

Comment: In the states, we say construction **site** or building **site**, but I was referring more to the verbs, not the nouns. But other than that, it's the same thing.  You didn't go into the construction/building site thing. No worries. It's amazing the extent to which there are no differences in fact.

Comment: Would you say construct or build a diagram from the data?

Comment: @skan If I were talking about it conceptually I'd probably use *construct*, but if about the painstaking job of doing it, then probably *build*.

Answer (score 2):

You are generally correct that the two words have very similar meanings.

> We can *build* a house but the place where we do it is called a *construction* site.

**Building site** is often used in BrE.

> We can *construct* a house but the result will be a *building* and not a *construction*.

When **construction** is used, it is often a qualifier for the materials used

> The *building* is a *construction* of glass, steel, and concrete.
>   The *building* is a *constructed* with glass, steel, and concrete.
>   It is *constructed* using glass, steel, and concrete.

> We can ***build*** a house and then ***reconstruct*** it but we can't ***construct*** a house and then ***rebuild*** it.

Not so, a house can be ***rebuilt*** or ***reconstructed***, the former usually means the house was destroyed and replaced on the same location,

> The houses destroyed by the tornado were ***rebuilt*** within two years.

the latter may mean it was made on a new location or is a facsimile of an original

> A copy of the castle was ***reconstructed*** in his backyard.
>   The movie is a ***reconstruction*** of the events that occurred.